# Javascript: functions as parameters, possibilities

Tags: javascript, function

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this in Javascript:

```
one(plus(nine())); // returns 10
```

It seems so, but I'm not sure how I'd pass the value of one() to the plus() function.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: For this trivial example, I could simply have `one = plus = nine = function() { return 10; }`. You need a far more complete specification of what is and isn't allowed to implement this

Comment: @Eric What is the name of the technique OP seems to be asking about?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's probably currying

Comment: @Th0rndike not in this form.

Comment: @NinaScholz agreed, he can't use 'one' as the external function

Comment: *"I'd pass the value of one() to the plus() function"* You wouldn't because `plus` is executed before `one`. But `plus` could return a function to which `one` can pass a value to.

Comment: @evolutionxbox not sure which _exact_ technique you are talking about. Very generally, this might be referred to as "higher order functions" although it's not really a technique but what allows this syntax/behaviour. More specifically but still general, this will fall under "functional programming". And the closest thing from there seems to be "functional composition" although that just deals with _nesting_ functions (more or less) - `c = one(); b = two(c); a = three(b);` can be represented as `a = three(two(one()))` and you can compose these via `giveA = compose(one, two, three); a = giveA()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One such choice would be to define (using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for conciseness<sup>1</sup>):

```
// creates a function that either returns the number, or forwards the number
// as an argument to the provided function
//   createNumber(10)() == 10
//   createNumber(9)(Math.sqrt) == 3
var createNumber = value => f => f ? f(value) : value;

var one = createNumber(1);
var nine = createNumber(9);

// A very basic curryed implementation of addition
//   plus(1)(2) == 3
var plus = a => b => a + b;
```

Which gives your required behaviour of

```
> one(plus(nine())
10
```

And a whole bunch of equally misguided but correct behaviour

```
> nine()
9
> nine(plus(one()))
10
> plus(nine())(one())
10
> nine(plus)(one())
10
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>: See [Vincenzo Maggio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40267071/102441</sup>) for the translation into standard anonymous functions</sup>

Comment: Now that's one hell of a solution. Very nice.

Comment: This is awesome. The biggest downside seems to be having to create a function for each number used.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Well you have to create something for each number used, and since the OP require it be callable, I see no other way.

Comment: that tricky trick you made on first line of code made my day. Gtz!

Comment: Honestly, I don't think there is. The closest solution I can think of is currying.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess you could run the code inside a `with` statement which resolves identifiers using a proxy object. That proxy could translate the identifier name from English to the appropriate number. This way you could reference arbitrary numbers without allocating all the possible functions beforehand. But that would be so dirty.

Comment: this answer made me to open a notebook.

Comment: @Oriol so so dirty.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Javascript being a prototype/functional language can create new functions and pass them around

```
//Returns a function that called without parameters extract the internal number
function number(num = null) {
  return function(op) {
    if (op == null) return num
      else return op(num)
  }
}

function plus(n1) {
  return function(n2) {
    return n2 + n1
  }
}

var one = number(1)
var nine = number(9)

document.write(one(plus(nine())))
```

I've saved [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2rzr6ve/3/) for you to play around if you need.

Comment: This is the same as my answer, but I guess having a translation of arrow-functions is handy, so **+1** :)

Comment: Well I didn't even know that they existed. I've written my answer without seeing yours, sorry if it seemed cloned.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, definitely.

However, You'll need to use some twisted logic that might not be too clean and You'll have an absurdly hard time making it actually useful.

One possible practical solution to this specific problem:

```js
nine = function(c) {

  if (typeof c === "object" && typeof c.method !== "undefined") {
    return c.value + 9;
  } else {
    return 9;
  }

};

plus = function(a) {
  return {
    value: a,
    method: "+"
  }
};

one = function(c) {

  if (typeof c === "object" && typeof c.method !== "undefined") {
    return c.value + 1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }

};

console.log( one( plus( nine() ) ) ) // -> 10
console.log( nine( plus( one() ) ) ) // -> 10
console.log( nine() )                // -> 9
console.log( one() )                 // -> 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Every function in JavaScript is a Function object.

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called.

So, just like objects can be passed from one function to another you can **pass a function reference**.

For example:

```
function add(var a, var b){
   return a+b;
}

function multiply(var a, var b){
    return a*b;
}

var compute(var a, var b, var operation){

    console.log(operation(a,b));

}
```

Once you add the paranthesis `()`, the function gets called immediately and it no longer is a reference. If you happen to assign the return value of the execution of the function it is  assigned to a LHS variable.

Eg: `var result = compute(10,20,add); // 20`

otherwise it is simply lost with the function stack frame where compute is called.